# Simple Bayes Classifier - Error of function predict

Tags: r

I am trying to run a simple bayes classification but I am having trouble with the function predict.
When I run my code, I get a factor with 0 levels. 
There are 8 variables from a speed dating dataset from Kaggle. The one being predicted is "match". There are no NA's. 
I have separated women from men. Then I divided my dataset of women "Bayes_data_women" into a train and a test one. 
Here is my code:

```
train_index <- sample(1:nrow(Bayes_data_women), 0.8 * nrow(Bayes_data_women))
test_index <- setdiff(1:nrow(Bayes_data_women), train_index)
train <- Bayes_data_women[train_index, -15]
test <- Bayes_data_men[test_index, -15]

model_women <- naiveBayes(match ~ ., data = train)
default_pred <- predict(model_women, newdata=test)
table(default_pred, test$match,dnn=c("Prediction","Actual"))
```

The code runs, but I get : default_pred : Factor w/ 0 levels

Thank you in advance.

Comment: naiveBayes is not part of base R. What library are you using?

Comment: @G5W I have these : install.packages('e1071', dependencies = TRUE)
library(class) 
library(e1071) 
library(mlbench) ! :)

Comment: You do not provide a sample of your data, so it is hard to know what is going on.  However, I suspect that `match` is variable number 15, so NB can't do anything with `naiveBayes(match ~ ., data = train) ` because `train` does not have a `match` variable.

Comment: @G5W I am sorry I do not know how to put my data on my post as I am new to stack overflow but the train and test set both have the same number and same variables :8 with the first column being "match" in both.

Comment: I have changed my code to  `train <- Bayes_data_women[train_index,]
test <- Bayes_data_men[test_index,]` but it still gives me the same factor with 0 levels so I cannot do the confusion matrix ..

Comment: The original dataset contains 195 variables, and although we can assume that you stay with 8 variables, apparently the code says that you eliminate variable # 15 can you clarify that? On the other hand, it would also be a good practice to improve the reproducibility to indicate the random seed.